# Consulta SQL mariadb 10.1.21

Tags: sql, mariadb

Tengo una tabla llamada jp que tiene los nombres y el identificador de partido(idp)
la pk sería idjp

`nombre idp equipo posicion idjp
javi     11    A      1      33
alex     11    A      2      34
pepe     11    B      1      35
juan     11    B      2      36`

tambien tengo la table votos para que cada grupo pueda votar a sus compañeros, aqui la pk seria idv. La tabla jp propaga su clave primaria idjp a la tabla votos que es la siguiente

```
idv  votado voto idp puntuacion idjp
1    alex   javi 11     5       34
2    alex   pepe 11     5       34 
3    javi   pepe 11     4       33
```

me gustaría hacer una consulta que mostrara

```
posicion nombre voto puntuacion
1         javi   NULL  NULL
2         alex   javi   5
```

para ello tengo una consulta que no me muestra lo anterior solo me muestra los que tienen votos, me gustaria que tambien me mostrase los que no tienen votos, tambien me gustaría que solo fueran mostrados los datos del usuario que votó(columna voto), la consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT jp.posicion ,jp.nombre, votos.voto ,votos.puntuacion 
from jp left join votos on (jp.idp=votos.idp and jp.nombre=votos.votado)
 where jp.idp=11 and jp.equipo='A' and votos.voto='javi'
```

esto simplemente me devuelve

```
posicion nombre voto puntuacion
2         alex   javi   5
```

Gracias, Un saludo

Comment: Esto es un ejercicio de la facultad o un caso real? sin resolver el problema (toadvia), veo que tus tablas no estan normalizadas correctamente. Nombre+idp no puede ser nunca PK de ninguna tabla. Que pasa si escribi mal mi nombre? votado no deberia ser un varchar, que pasa si alguien puso mal su nombre? Lo que no entiendo bien, es de donde salen cada campo en la consulta final, ya que todos los datos parecen estar en la tabla votos...

Comment: No es un ejercicio de la facultad, es un caso real, en la practica la tabla jp tiene un idjp que es la clave primaria pero para no complicar mas el ejercicio no le he puesto porque el nombre y el idp tienen que ser unicos en la tabla jp.
Necesito que si el nombre esta en la tabla votos que salga con su puntuacion y si no que lo tome de la tabla jp el nombre y ponga la puntuacion a null

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @gbianchi, tu modelo de datos no es correcto. Si quieres y puedes es mejor que lo corrijas, pero para eso debes explicar un poco mejor el contexto, porque la pregunta no es que sea muy clara.

Comment: Y si de tu query sacas votos.voto = javi? Pq eso parece ser lo que filtra esos nulos

Comment: si quito votos.voto='javi'  veria los votos que les han dado los otros usuarios y lo que me interesa es ver los que ha dado el usuario que esta en la sesion en este ejemplo javi.
El contexto es jp es la tabla intermedia generada de una relacion N:M entre partidos y jugadores y de ahi se relaciona con votos cada nombre en jp tiene n votos y un voto pertenece a un unico nombre de jp por lo que la relacion es 1:N , yo creo que el modelo de datos es correcto

Comment: No miré bien pero, qué resultado obtienes si, en lugar de left join, usas right join?

Comment: El resultado no varia si utilizo right join . Es el mismo resultado que con left.
Gracias por responder

Comment: No javier. Algo esta mal. Porque queres mostrar dos registros entonces? si vos pones votos.voto = javi lo unico que va a traer esa consulta son los registros que sean igual a ese dato. y null no es igual a eso. Por eso, te pasa lo que te pasa. Vos queres otra cosa, pero no lo estas sabiendo explicar. Tal vez queres los que sean votos.voto = javi, y tambien a los que voto javi? y esa es otra cosa totalmente diferente...

Comment: Necesito que salgan los resultados en los que votos.voto es igual a javi y si no hay ninguno que concuerde con javi que salga el otro jugador del equipo para que  lo puedan votar que en este caso es javi[https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=53d4ee1fab1ed10244866a44d4940328]